# Custom URL for a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, url

(Hopefully) simple question: How do you configure a custom URL for your Facebook App? I know right now it works as https://apps.facebook.com/[APP_ID]/, but is it possible to make/request a URL of your choosing? For example, https://apps.facebook.com/chickenwings/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, create a namespace in your app settings.

[image: chickenwings in app settings]

Comment: Well. That was almost too easy. Thanks!

Comment: Very cool. do you know if this works for page tab apps too?
I can't seem to get it work for those.